# Getting Error Access denied for user 'acctname'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Tags: php

I installed MAMP several weeks ago and have been using it for PHP development without any problems.  I recently developed a script that will count how many times per day a link has been clicked, and it works flawlessly.  Now I need to display the information in the web browser.

After making sure I was connected to the database I wrote the following:

```
    $query = "SELECT * FROM banners";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    if (!$result) die ("Database access failed: " . mysql_error());
```

When I go to the page to check to see if there is an error I see

Database access failed: Access denied for user 'acctname'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

What is going on and how can I fix it?

Thanks.

EDIT: Nevermind. I figured it out.  Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to make sure that user has SELECT privileges for the "banners" table.  You can click on Privileges in phpMySQLAdmin website.

Comment: Yes I had privileges set up correctly, it was another issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In your example I do not see that you are making a connection to the DB and selecting a database to run the query against.  Are you doing something like the following prior to your query?

```
mysql_connect($host, $username, $password);
mysql_select_db($database_name);
```

Comment: "After making sure I was connected to the database..."

Comment: I figured out the issue but yes I was connected to the database.  I had included a connection file.

Comment: Can you please post the answer of how you fixed it, so future generations who have the same issue can check it out?